# Ejecutar java (eclipse) en otro entorno

Tags: java, eclipse, consola

He hecho un programa con eclipse (sin interfaz gráfica) y me gustaría poderlo ejecutar fuera del programa, por ejemplo en la consola, o con la estética de la consola. Similar a cuando programas con el codeblocks y te crea el ejecutable. El hecho es que he encontrado videos y post que comentan poder ejecutar desde consola pero ninguno de ellos me ha funcionado. Además el programa requiere interacción con el usuario y con archivos.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar los pasos que has realizado?

Comment: He provado de exportarlo en jar (no me ha funcionado) y he provado de ejecutarlo des de la consola situandome en la carpeta en la que esta y tratando de ejecutarlo des de alli, y tampoco he logrado nada

Comment: En la consola deberás compilar el fichero antes

Comment: y como hago eso?

Comment: Tendrás que hacer `javac tufichero.java`. Y después, `java tufichero` para que se ejecute.

Comment: "javac" nos e reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que teienes es generar el .jar del programa. En eclipse, pulsas el botón derecho sobre tu proyecto y pulsas "Export...". Se abrirá una ventana con varias opciones; Despliegas la opción Java, seleccionas Runnable JAR file y pulsas Next.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente ventana, en el desplegable "Launch configuration" eliges la clase de tu proyecto que desees que ejecute el programa (la clase que contiene la función main) y eliges la ruta donde quieres que se exporte tu archivo JAR.

Una vez hecho esto, abres la consola y te situas en el directorio que contiene el fichero JAR y ejecutas "java -jar miprograma.jar". A partir de ahí se ejecutará tu programa como lo hace eclipse en su consola.

Tambien puedes ejecutar el comando anterior introduciendo la ruta del fichero.

Answer (score 0):

@Error404 tiene razón aunque si se ha creado una aplicación puede que haya varios escenarios en los que se deba hacer más cosas:

1. Hay una clase sin paquete
2. Hay una clase dentro de paquete(s)
3. Hay multiples clases
4. Hay múltiples clases en múltiples paquetes.

Dependiendo del escenario pues varía un poco la forma en que se puede hacer ésto:

*Asumiendo que JAVA_HOME ha sido agregado a las [variables de entorno](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=389:configurar-java-en-windows-variables-de-entorno-javahome-y-path-cu00610b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188) y que el programa se llama "ProgramaX" y se encuentra en "C://"*

### 1

Si existe una sola clase:

Se abre la consola y se va a la ubicación del programa:

*`WINDOWS+R >> cmd >> ENTER >> cd C://ProgramaX/src/ >> ENTER`*

Su ubicación debería mostrarle el archivo.java si digita `dir >> ENTER`.

Luego para ejecutar el programa:

```
javac ClaseUnica.java & java ClaseUnica >> ENTER
```

### 2

Si hay un paquete de por medio por ejemplo `src/paquete/ClaseUnica.java` entonces nos ubicamos en la carpeta `src/` y:

```
javac paquete/ClaseUnica.java & java paquete.ClaseUnica >> ENTER
```

### 3

Si hay múltiples clases pues hay que compilar todas las clases primero y luego ejecutar la clase que tenga el método `main`:

```
javac paquete/*.java >> ENTER
java paquete.ClasePrincipal >> ENTER
```

### 4

Si hay múltiples clases en múltiples paquetes también se puede como en la opción **3** pero ésto ya se vuelve muy tedioso. Lo mejor sería crear un `JAR` y luego simplemente ejecutarlo desde la consola. (ésta opción funciona para todas las anteriores)

Click derecho sobre el proyecto en eclipse, click sobre la opción `export`, escribir en el filtro "runn", aparece *Runnable JARfile*, click en ésta opción y click en `Next`, en *Launch Configurations*, Seleccionar la clase que tenga el método `main`, y seleccionar como destino de exportación `C://ProyectoX/src/` y para que no haya que movernos de donde estamos en la consola, click en `Finish`.

Luego desde la consola si escribe `dir >> ENTER` debería Ver el nuevo `Archivo.jar`.

Para ejecutarlo:

```
java -jar NombreEjecutable.jar >> ENTER
```

Hay otras formas de realizar éstas tareas que es utilizando una herramienta de construcción como [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) pero pues ésto ya tiene una curva de aprendizaje más grande.

### Edit

**Cómo agregar JAVA_HOME** a las variables de entorno para que el error

> javac no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo ....

Desaparezca:

1. WINDOWS + r
2. Digitar: "sysdm.cpl" ENTER
3. Seleccionar pestaña "Opciones Avanzadas"
4. Click en "Variables de entorno"
5. Click en "nueva" variable del sistema
6. Nombre de la variable: "JAVA_HOME"
7. valor de variable: "C://ubicacion/java/jdk1.x.x/"

*En mi caso fue: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\"*

8. Buscar la **variable de sistema** ## Path ##
9. Click en editar (NO BORRE NADA DE LO QUE YA HAYA)
10. Al final del valor de la variable, agregar un ";" si NO existe
11. Agregar "%JAVA_HOME%/bin"
12. Aceptar, aceptar etc ...

Comment: "javac" nos e reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Es un solo archivo que tiene el Main y todo dentro de una sola classe

Comment: Eso pasa porque no esta el `JAVA_HOME` en las variables de entorno, mire el link que le deje al principio

Comment: lo hice tal cual lo indica

Comment: si, si, tal cual lo has puesto, pero no me funciona xD

Comment: Cierre y abra de nuevo cmd si no lo ha hecho, de lo contrario pues toca que actualice su pregunta con más detalles, imagenes etc ..

Comment: [img]http://i.imgur.com/mLMhfeW.png[/img]

este es el codigo, no se si presenta algun problema

Comment: Si eclipse no le muestra errores es porque está bien, pero ésto no tiene nada que ver con correr java desde la consola. Creo que necesita es ver un tutorial para principiantes. http://www.cursopedia.com/Ficha-Curso-de-Java-para-principiantes